# Twig file - Make all the fields appear in a single column instead of 2 columns

Tags: php, drupal, twig

I am having a twig template for my view on which the fields are displayed on 2 columns. Is there a way to make all the fields appear in the same column?

Twig code:

```
{% set index = 0 %}
<div class='row'>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
       {% for key, field in fields -%}

        {% if index == 0 or index == 5 %}
        <div class='col-md-6'>
        {% endif %}

            <span {{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</span>

            <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ tooltips[key] }}">
              <span {{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</span><br/>
            </a>


        {% if index + 1 == fields | length %}
          <a href=''>Test link</a>
          {% endif %}
        {% if index == 4 or index + 1 == fields | length  %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% set index = index + 1 %}
      {%- endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Current output:
[image]
How to make all the fields appear in one single column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple fix. I removed the class from  panel and it brought all the fields in a single column.

```
<div class='col-md-6'> changed to just <div> tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not wrap the class in css using flex-direction: column.. for example:

```
.panel-body{
  display:flex
  flex-direction: column
}
```